# Its possible to create a bezier semicircle Xamarin Forms SkiaSharp

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

Hi im trying to reproduce something like this

[image: demo]

Im following the reply in this [Issue](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/813) , but im not able to get any close to what is in the image.

**EDIT**: Im adding what i have done so far , as you can see in the image i cant get the perfect round when curve ends.

[image: work]

```
        private void SKCanvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
        {
            SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
            SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;
            canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);

            float canvasWidth = canvas.LocalClipBounds.Width;
            float canvasHeight = canvas.LocalClipBounds.Height;

            using (SKPath bezierPath = new SKPath())
            {
                //Start at bottom
                bezierPath.MoveTo(0, canvasHeight);

                bezierPath.LineTo(0, canvasHeight * 0.6f);

                bezierPath.LineTo(canvasWidth * 0.2f, canvasHeight * 0.6f);

                bezierPath.CubicTo(canvasWidth * 0.4f, canvasHeight * 0.6f,
                                   canvasWidth * 0.5f, canvasHeight * 0f,
                                   canvasWidth * 0.8f, canvasHeight * 0.6f);

                bezierPath.LineTo(canvasWidth, canvasHeight * 0.6f);
                bezierPath.LineTo(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

                bezierPath.Close();

                canvas.DrawPath(bezierPath, _paint);
            }
        }
```

Comment: you need to show us the code you're actually using and the result you're actually getting

Comment: I edited the post with more info.

Comment: your X coordinates for the bezier curve are not equidistant, which seems like it could be a problem

Comment: this may help - https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/VS4Mac-SkiaSharpFiddle